# Why did Tiffany call's premium increase, when its stock price decreased?

Tags: call

My grandma has been tracking TIF in the news, and recorded its option premiums. On Jun 9 2020, 1 TIF 2022-01-22 135C sold for \$0.88. On Jun 10 2020, it sold for \$0.5. Today, it sold for $1.6. Which specific variable caused it to increase? She expected TIF's call  premiums to tumble, when TIF's share price plummeted after ["Luxury goods giant LVMH cancels \$14.5B deal for Tiffany"](https://old.reddit.com/r/business/comments/iphi9k/luxury_goods_giant_lvmh_cancels_145b_deal_for/g4l6k1c/) on 9.9.2020, allegedly by reason of [tariffs](https://old.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/ipi7xd/lvmh_pulled_the_plug_on_its_acquisition_of/g4k57mx/).

I read [Why Did My Stock Go Up and My Call Option Go Down? • TradeSmart University](https://tradesmartu.com/blog/why-did-my-stock-go-up-and-my-call-option-go-down/) and [How Can A Call Option Decline In Value When A Stock Rises?](https://optionalpha.com/how-can-a-call-option-decline-in-value-when-a-stock-rises-10771.html). I don't think US interest rates changed these past 2 days, so $\rho \approx 0$. So I'm surmising that IV rose, so $\nu \uparrow$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From June to September, the time to expiry went from about 1.5 years to 1.25 years. Recently, volatility has gone up as well. The bid-ask spread in long-dated out-of-the-money options can also be very wide. Put that all together and what you are seeing is not surprising.

You can go to [the OCC](https://www.theocc.com) to see implied vols as well as some quote information.